# Normalize / Standardize in a Random Forest?

Tags: statistics, random-forest, matrix

If I have a matrix of co-occurring words in conversations of different lengths, is it appropriate to standardize / normalize the data prior to training?

My matrix is set up as follows: one row per two-person conversation, and columns are the words that co-occur between speakers. I cannot help but think that, as a longer conversation will likely comprise more shared words than shorter ones, I should factor this in somehow.

Comment: So your matrix is comprised of words as columns, and they take the value of 1 if they appear in the conversation ( row ) ?

Comment: They appear as co-occurring word counts. So if the word 'hello' co-occurs more than once in the conversation it is counted for each additional repetition

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for the clarification by commenting. Tree-based models do not care about the **absolute** value that a feature takes. They only care about the **order** of the values. 
Hence, normalization is used mainly in linear models/knn/neural networks because they're affected by absolute values taken by features.

You don't need to normalize/standardize.

Check this [post](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/5277/do-you-have-to-normalize-data-when-building-decision-trees-using-r).